# NodeJS sync call

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I am trying to fetch the number of records from Database using nodejs but the problem is that due to sync requests , I am not able to print them. When I try to print it inside the function , it prints fine but outside the function , it doesn't. I know it is due to sync behavior of JS but I want to do this (may be asynchronsly) . I am very new to Javascript and nodejs , so please guide me how can I do this. here is the code.

```
router.post('/numofrecs', function(req, res) {

        var db = new Db('nmydb', new Server('localhost', '27017'));
        db.open(function (err, db) {
        db.authenticate('', '', function (err, result) {


            var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/nmydb';
            client.connect(url, function (err, db) {
                que = new Array();
                var questioncol = db.collection('allquestions');
                questioncol.find({}).count(function (err, data) {
                    rec = data;
                    console.log("Num of rec:"+rec);
                    //inside the connect function , it prints fine here
                });

                console.log('Num of rec:'+ rec);


//but it doesnot print here outside the connect function and just print "undefined"
```

Comment: Your problem is due to the *asynchronous* nature of the database connector you are using. Unless that connector provides a synchronous alternative, what you are trying to do can't be done.

Comment: really :( it can't be done???

Comment: Right, all code that relies on `rec` will need to be within a callback, unless the connector provides a synchronous alternative.

Comment: Note however that synchronous actions on an http server are very bad. It will lock your server until that synchronous action is complete, meaning the server will not receive or respond to any requests until the synchronous action is complete.

Comment: can you please provide me a chunk of code in answer that how can I do it with call back because there is some code which is dependent on value of "rec"

Comment: You have already provided that in your question. Simply remove the last `console.log` and you would pretty much have the answer i would provide.

Comment: I want to do some calculations with "rec" , so should I write a function inside the `connect` function after getting the value of rec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are building an HTTP server, you do not want to have any synchronous actions on your server because such actions would result in your server becoming unresponsive to all clients during the synchronous action. Instead, you should do the work you need within the callback of the db query.

```
router.post('/numofrecs', function(req, res) {
    var db = new Db('nmydb', new Server('localhost', '27017'));
    db.open(function (err, db) {
        db.authenticate('', '', function (err, result) {
            var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/nmydb';
            client.connect(url, function (err, db) {
                var que = new Array();
                var questioncol = db.collection('allquestions');
                questioncol.find({}).count(function (err, data) {
                    console.log("Num of rec:"+data);
                    // do stuff with data here.
                    doStuff(data);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Don't forget to `var` your variables.

Answer (score 0):

npm install -g xd-synchttp

```
const sync = require('xd-synchttp');
let content = "";
let post_data={'a':1,'b':2};
try{
    content = sync.http_get('http://www.csdn.net',3);
    console.log(sync.http_post('http://www.baidu.com',post_data,0));
}
catch(err){
console.log(err);
}
```